# Heimdall could not able to detect Samsung Galaxy Tab P1000?

Tags: android, development-environment

I am trying to flash Samsung Galaxy Tab P1000 using Heimdall commands in Linux.

issue:

```
sudo heimdall detect
```

command not supoorting to detect device but device is detected becase

```
sudo heimdall print-pit
```

command is working and rebooting device ... but I could not able to Flash it.

Pls help,

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a programming question. Please use other resources, such as http://android.stackexchange.com, or wherever Heimdall support can be found, for Heimdall questions.

Comment: What error message are getting when attempt to flash device? Also are you using `heimdall --recovery ./location/file --no-reboot`?

Answer (score 1):

Device detection in Heimdall:

1. First off, go in Download mode: With the Samsung Galaxy TAB turned off, press and hold the VOLUME Down button, and then briefly press the POWER button.
2. Plug in connection cable to your device and USB.
3. Only after that Heimdall will detect your device, if it's detectable :)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some great information now on the [Lineage OS wiki](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/n5110/install). They then advise to install [twrp](https://twrp.me/Devices/) using heimdall to flash your tablet with a new OS.

Samsung devices come with a unique boot mode called “Download mode”, which is very similar to “Fastboot mode” on some devices with unlocked bootloaders.

1. Download and install the [Heimdall suite](http://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/#downloads):

   - **Linux**: Pick the appropriate package to install for your distribution. The `-frontend` packages aren’t needed for this guide. After installation, verify Heimdall is installed by running `heimdall version` in the terminal.
2. Power off the device and connect the USB adapter to the computer (but not to the device, yet).
3. Boot into download mode:

   - With the device powered off, hold <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>.
4. On the computer, open a terminal and type:

   ```
   heimdall print-pit
   ```
5. If the device reboots, Heimdall is installed and working properly.